# Network request quiet slow on apple watch using NSURLSession

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I have a watch app using the same API as it is on iPhone. The request code are total same. But the response time on watch is slower than iPhone about 3-4 seconds. Is this normal? Can we improve this experience on watch?

Thank.

Comment: Will it be faster if I ask for iPhone to fetch data in background and send the response data to Watch.

Answer (score 3):

First, comparing Apple Watch's speed with iPhone, no matter what area that is, is **pointless**.

Apple Watch is smaller in size, which has less battery, less CPU power and a much smaller antenna. It should be *so much slower* than iPhone. That's part of the reason it's been locked out from lots of standard iOS APIs. You already saw how slow when it loads an app before 3.0 beta.

Secondly, although Apple Watch support WiFi, unlike iPhone, it supports only 802.11b/g/n 2.4GHz. Not 5GHz or ac.

Keep in mind that it's an extension of your iPhone, not a standalone device that to be used extensively like you do to your iPhone. If it's slow, maybe you shouldn't let it do it at the first place. Instead, use your phone to do the work and send the data to your Watch.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did need refresh the data on watch. Can you give some more detail?